# Does this cause a retain cycle?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I connected a `UISegmentedControl` object from the `.xib` file to the corresponding  `IBOutle UISegmentedControl` `ivar` in the `ViewController.h`. Then I put this method in the `ViewController.m`:

```
-(IBAction)switchMapTypes {
    if (switchMapTypes.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        [worldView setMapType: MKMapTypeStandard];

    else if (switchMapTypes.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
        [worldView setMapType: MKMapTypeSatellite];

    else if (switchMapTypes.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
        [worldView setMapType: MKMapTypeHybrid];
}
```

Will this cause a retain cycle if I link this method back to the `UISegmentedControl` object in the `.xib` file? Or am I completely misunderstanding what a retain cycle is?

Comment: You completely misunderstood it. There are two primary reason (IMHO) for having cycles: you instantiate something like a NSTimer, that in turn retains YOU. If you forget to get rid of it when you prepare to release, then you won't get released (RETAIN CYCLE). Likewise if some object is has your class as a delegate but retains you (some apple classes do this). A third uncommon way is you declare a block and store it as an object, but it has retained "self". Sure there are other ways. Note that when using NIBs, only "top level objects" need "strong" all else should be "weak".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A retain cycle happens when an object owns another object that in turn owns the first. Your segemented control doesn't claim ownership of the view controller -- hooking up an `IBAction` has no ownership consequences -- so there's no cycle here.

There's a style issue, though. You appear to have a method which is not a getter that has the same name as an ivar, `switchMapTypes`. You should not use the same name for two such different things. Also, your ivar name should really be a noun, and the method (which is an action) a verb. I would suggest `mapTypesSwitch` for the ivar and `changeMapType` for the action.